# Docker - Canonical way of dns resolving container

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, docker

I have issues addressing container in my docker network. I understand the different kinds of networks like overlay, bridge, networks. But I don't understand how to make my container talk to each other.

Practical example:
I have a web server. There are two docker container on my web server. The first one holds nginx. The second one an instance of gitlab.

I need to point nginx with the proxy_pass variable to my gitlab container.

Here are the two ways I know how to do it:

1. I add links to my docker container. Docker deprecated those, so that's not an option.
2. I am using a dnsdock. I am using aacebedo's dnsdock docker. It allows me to provide container with dns resolvable names by giving them the `com.dnsdock.alias` flag.

Is that the normal way of doing it? Is there not some better integrated way of solving that issue without adding a dns server to the network?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the canonical answer.

1. I create a network for my docker container.
2. I provide them with a net-alias.

Now docker will resolve them via the net-alias. As an added bonus, this probably allows for hassle-free overlay networking between servers. But I haven't tested it, so don't nail me down on this.